How to check if a point lies inside a tetrahedron
Given a tetrahedron $T$ with apex $O$ and vertices $V_1, V_2, V_3$ and point $P=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ in $3$D space. I need to check programmatically if $P$ lies inside $T$.

We can also assume the angle between apex $O$ and each leg is $90'$.

Do you know how to check a point lies in which side of a plane?

@Trebor  We can use the equation of the plane and substitute the coordinates of the point into the equation. If the result is close to zero (within a small tolerance), then the point lies on the plane.

No, I'm talking about which side (left or right, for example), not on the plane.

@Trebor If the substitution result is positive it is left and negative right. Right?

what have you tried? some solutions readily show up on a search engine, such as volume decomposition or barycentric coordinates

@vallev I tried to form the plane equation, but since I need it to be implemented efficiently in a programming language, it is an inefficient solution.

If the barycentric coordinates $\lambda_i$ are non-negative and sum to 1 then the point P lies inside the tetrahedron. It suffices to solve the system: $$\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_p \
y_p \
z_p \
1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 \
z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4 \
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
\lambda_1 \
\lambda_2 \
\lambda_3 \
\lambda_4
\end{array}\right]$$

@vallev It will be easier for future readers of the post if you turn your comment into an answer.

Some algorithmic solutions over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179693/how-to-check-whether-the-point-is-in-the-tetrahedron-or-not

Given any point P and vertices $V_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ with $i=1,2,3,4$ you can describe the point as a convex combination of the coordinates of each vertex. These are called Barycentric coordinates.
If the barycentric coordinates $\lambda_i$ are non-negative and sum to 1 then the point $P$ lies inside the tetrahedron. It suffices to solve the system:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_p \\
y_p \\
z_p \\
1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 \\
z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 \\
\lambda_3 \\
\lambda_4
\end{array}\right]
$$
You can do this in constant time.
def is_point_in_tetrahedron(P, A, B, C, D):
    M = np.array([
        [A[0], B[0], C[0], D[0]],
        [A[1], B[1], C[1], D[1]],
        [A[2], B[2], C[2], D[2]],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]
    ])
    P_vec = np.array([P[0], P[1], P[2], 1])
    try:
        lambdas = np.linalg.solve(M, P_vec)
        return all(l >= 0 for l in lambdas) and np.isclose(np.sum(lambdas), 1)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return False

# Example usage:
A = (1, 0, 0)
B = (0, 1, 0)
C = (0, 0, 1)
D = (1, 1, 1)
P = (0.25, 0.25, 0.25)

print(is_point_in_tetrahedron(P, A, B, C, D))  # Should return True


Your code returned False

@MamaD as it should ! https://www.desmos.com/3d/prxa8xdabg :)

Here is a method
that works for
any convex polyhedron
in any number of dimensions.
Get a point
inside the polyhedron.
The average of all the vertices
will do fine.
Call this the center.
Then,
for any plane and any point,
substitute the point
in the equation of the plane.
If this has the same sign
as when the center is
substituted in the equation of the plane,
the point is on the
same side of the plane
as the center.
Do this for
all the boundary planes
(n-1 simplices for
an n-dimensional polyhedron,
the four bounding planes
for a tetrahedron).
If your point is on
the same side
of all the boundary planes
as the center,
it is inside the polyhedron.
If this is done in floating point,
there may be
numerical instability issues.
If all the computations
are done using rational numbers,
there should be no problem.
As with many of my answers,
nothing here is original.
